# mariadb install failure (OSX 10.10.2)

Tags: installation, mariadb

> Generic Build instructions:
>   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/generic-build-instructions/

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.4.0-rc3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

$ cmake . -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release

$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

$ make

...
...

Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:191:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:222:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:423:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:452:5: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
    try {
    ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:465:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:552:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:576:5: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
    try {
    ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:592:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:617:5: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
    try {
    ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:616:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:652:5: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
    try {
    ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:651:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:703:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:811:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:864:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:921:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:969:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:1007:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
/Users/7stud/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/dat.cpp:1101:3: error: 
      cannot use 'try' with exceptions disabled
  try {
  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/dat.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/lib/CMakeFiles/libgroonga.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
~/Downloads/mariadb-10.1.8$
```

Comment: @Janus Troelsen, I posted this failure over at the mariaDB website, and it's a bug that's now scheduled to be fixed in mariaDB version 10.1.9.  See here:   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/install-problem-on-mac-osx-10102/

Comment: 10.1.9 was already released! Thanks!

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, Thanks for letting me know.  I'll give it another try.

Comment: I would suggest using a VM (virtualbox or similar) with some linux on it as mariadb server, this will make your life waaaaay easier (IMHO)

Comment: @RC, After trying to use Vagrant/VirtualBox twice over the years, I gave up.  Their simple demo resulted in warnings both times I tried it, and the developer wasn't helpful when I inquired about the warnings.  I found it surprising that the developer couldn't put together a simple demo with his own software that would run error/warning free.

Comment: I don't say you should use vagrant, just a plain old VM and a plain old linux iso. Installing virtualbox is like any other software double-click, next next done. And [installing linux on virtualbox](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox) is not complicated. Finally, mariadb install is just a `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`. The only "difficult" part is to understand how the networking between VM and host works.